# Problemas creando una tabla con FPDF

Tags: php

Quiero crear una tabla como esta con FPDF, y que se vayan añadiendo mas tablas como estas segun los datos que me devuelve una consulta. Aun asi, con tener una plantilla de la tabla me sirve

Esta es la tabla:

[image: Tabla]

El codigo html de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="335">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" rowspan="4" colspan="2"><img width="64" height="64" id="_x0000_i1025" src=""></td>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3" style="height:37px;">

            </td>           
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">

            </td>


        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">

            </td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">

            </td>                                       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">

            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Por ahora tengo este código:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'D',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,'',1);
$pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Output();
```

Que me muestra esta tabla

[image: TABLA2]

Tengo problemas para crear saltos de linea y unir columnas de tipo `colspan` o `rowspan`

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58953/discussion-on-question-by-andoni-alda-problemas-creando-una-tabla-con-fpdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una biblioteca de funciones más versátil como es [`TCPDF`](https://tcpdf.org/).

Un ejemplo de cómo hacer uso de `ob_start()` para diseñar directamente el HTML que queremos generar en el PDF en el mismo archivo:

```
<?php
// Comenzamos a guardar todo el HTML generado en el búffer */
ob_start();
/* A partir de ahora podríamos hacer consultas SQL, generar tablas, cabeceras,
  y casi todo tipo de código HTML que será almacenado para su uso posterior */
?><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="335">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" rowspan="4" colspan="2"><img width="64" height="64" id="_x0000_i1025" src=""></td>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3" style="height:37px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-solid" colspan="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
            <td class=" border-left-solid">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
/* Guardamos el HTML generado en una variable para trabajar con ella */
$html = ob_get_contents();
/* Deshacemos todo lo generado y empezamos de nuevo */
ob_end_clean();

require 'TCPDF-6.2.13/tcpdf.php';

/* Creamos el documento PDF */
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
/* Agregamos la primera página */
$pdf->AddPage();
/* Generamos su contenido a partir del código HTML */
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
/* Damos salida del documento al navegador */
$pdf->Output('tu_pdf.pdf', 'I');
```